# Why is my assembly code exiting prematurely despite it working in a separate file?

Tags: assembly, arm

This assembly file is for my raspberry pi (ARM assembly). I'm converting this: 
`if(9<x && x<=10){
r0 += 7; //otherwise exit 
}`
Into assembly code, which is the bottom half of _start: . Simply, I have this:

```
     .global _start
_start:
     mov r0, #0
     mov r1, #10


     cmp r1, #5
     bgt _true

     cmp r1, #10 @ x < 10
     bge _else
     add r0, #3

    cmp r1, #9 @ *here is where the program messes up and exits*
    ble _exit
    cmp r1, #10
    bgt _exit
    mov r0, #7
_true:
       add r0, #1
_else:
       add r0, #5
_exit:
       mov r7, #1
       swi 0
```

I believe my logic is fine because I isolated the problem into a different .s file and it works perfectly.

```
     .global _start
    _start:
        cmp r1, #9 @ *this works as expected*
        ble _exit
        cmp r1, #10
        bgt _exit
        mov r0, #7
    _exit:
        mov r7, #1
        swi 0
```

I'm thinking I could solve this problem if I put this at the top half instead of the bottom, but I would like to know why this is happening. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

In terminal I run these command lines to build:

- as -o test1.o test1.s
- ld test1.o
- gdb a.out

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step through your code and see how it branches.  You said some version of this works, but you didn't give enough detail to understand what change made it work.  Also, you didn't say *how* it fails.  [mcve].  (And I don't feel like debugging it for you to find out what change would be needed.)  One common way for asm to work in one context but not another is accidentally depending on a register being zero or some other value when your code doesn't write it.  (Doesn't look like the case here; you only use r0 and r1.)

Comment: I have used the debugger. There is no need to be passive aggressive towards me. And that's why I'm asking this question, to understand why it works the way it does. (when the lines cmp r1, #9 to mov r0, #7 are put into a separate .s file) I thought that I was clear about that but apparently not.

Comment: No, that's not *at all* clear.  When you put it in a separate `.s` file, do you add a label to it and a `b` instruction to that label?  Or do you just link in the right order so the machine code from the two files ends up contiguous in the `.text` section of the linked executable?  I'm not being *passive* aggressive, I'm aggressively telling you to go use a debugger instead of asking SO questions with very few details.  And when you do ask, make sure you include critical info like how you build and run your code, and show what you're talking about.

Comment: I just updated the question. Hopefully, it suits your standards. If not, then sorry.

Comment: Yes, this is much better.  Thanks for taking the time to clean up your question, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  I wouldn't have guessed that's what you meant, because in your smaller example which "works", everything always falls through into `_exit` whether either branch is taken or not.  But you mean "works" as in you followed it with the debugger to see the branch you expected was taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal because after the first comparison will branch to _true (because !Z && N==O) and continue until the end (_else and _exit).

```
     .global _start
_start:
     mov r0, #0
     mov r1, #10


     cmp r1, #5
     bgt _true          @ It will branch to true because !Z && N==O
```

But, answering to your question, you have to jump to _exit after _true and _else (or branch with link (bl)), because if not, you will continue running instructions secuentially. In addition, if you don't want use *branch with link (bl)*, you can put _exit at the top and b _exit in _true and _else.

e.g.

```
     .global _start

_exit:
       mov r7, #1
       swi 0

_start:
     mov r0, #0
     mov r1, #10


     cmp r1, #5
     bgt _true

     cmp r1, #10 @ x < 10
     bge _else
     add r0, #3

    cmp r1, #9 @ *here is where the program messes up and exits*
    ble _exit
    cmp r1, #10
    bgt _exit
    mov r0, #7
_true:
       add r0, #1
       b _exit

_else:
       add r0, #5
       b _exit
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You were very helpful. :)

Comment: There's no benefit to putting `_exit` out of line.  You can have `_else` fall into it, saving that `b` instruction.  Or hoist the `mov r7, #1` ahead of the  conditional branches, and tail-duplicate that `swi 0`.  (Put an `_exit` label on one of them so the ble and bgt can jump to it.).  Of course, you can do the range-check with sub `r1, #9` / `cmp r1, #(10-9)` / `jhi _exit` (unsigned compare because low values below 9 wrap).  Anyway, still the right answer, just a slightly clunky solution to it.  (Most of the stuff I mentioned was a problem in the OP's code already.)